# How do I match nuget loose versions with LTS .net core versions?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

For the moment, while .net core 3.1 exists and has LTS, I am still living in a 2.x world.

rows below from

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

```
.NET Core 3.1   December 3, 2019    3.1.3   March 24, 2020  LTS December 3, 2022
.NET Core 2.2   December 4, 2018    2.2.8   November 19, 2019   EOL December 23, 2019
.NET Core 2.1   May 30, 2018    2.1.17  March 24, 2020  LTS August 21, 2021
```

So .net core 2.2 is EOL.  but .net core 2.1 is LTS.  Ok...

Now.......my question comes from these "loose" version numbers that some mainstream microsoft packages uses.

Let's take this one:

Microsoft.Extensions.Http

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/2.1.1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/2.2.0

Now.  If I target

```
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Should I only be using Microsoft.Extensions.Http/2.1.1 ? (the current "max" 2.1.x version)?

Or can I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http/2.2.0 ?

There a host of others that follow this loose pattern.

A few:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.1.2" />
```

Comment: If you create a project with target framework asp.net core 2.1,the project would contains default package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App  2.1.1`.And the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.1` exists in  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App  2.1.1` by default.

Comment: Thanks Rena.  That gives me a good strong hint.  And a clear dependency tree.

Comment: Rena, add your comment as an answer.  and I'll mark as the answer.  (I may tweak a tad since I just created some screen shots to explain to other devs) ..  I'd prefer to give someone (who was helpful) the mark-as-answer.

Comment: Hi @granadaCoder,I have added as an answer.Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,If you create a project with target framework `asp.net core 2.1`,the project would contains default package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1`.

Then the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.1` exists in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1` by default.

Answer (score 0):

As Rena suggests, here is a simple test:

Create a new Asp.Net Core Web Application.  "Empty" is ok for this exercise.  Target 2.1.

Now look at the dependencies. (Expand "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" especially)

Based on Rena's comment hint, I was able to "prove" this a bit better by finding this file:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.14\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.deps.json

Partial paste below.  But it is riddled with 2.1.1 and 2.1.x references.

Including the "example:

> "Microsoft.Extensions.Http": "2.1.1",

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1/win-x64",
    "signature": "79b634683a682f255cb6a59f29b434b972da8d01"
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1": {},
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1/win-x64": {
      "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.6": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Newtonsoft.Json": "11.0.2",
          "Newtonsoft.Json.Bson": "1.0.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "5.2.6.0",
            "fileVersion": "5.2.60510.0"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore/2.1.7": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "2.1.7",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.7.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.7.18340"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool": "2.1.6"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.13": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.6",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "2.1.7",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "2.1.8",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys": "2.1.12",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "2.1.7",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core": "2.1.7",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets": "2.1.3",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json": "1.0.4",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices": "2.1.13",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "2.1.7",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "2.1.11",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "2.1.10",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter": "2.1.0",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives": "2.1.6",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers": "2.1.1",
          "System.IO.Pipelines": "4.5.3"
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/2.1.8": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.8.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.8.19018"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "5.2.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.1.2",
          "Newtonsoft.Json": "11.0.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "5.2.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation": "5.2.0",
          "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.2.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "2.1.2"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions/2.1.3": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.1.1",
          "System.IO.Pipelines": "4.5.3"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.3.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.3.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy/2.1.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.2.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.2.18207"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal/2.1.1": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.5.0",
          "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml": "4.5.0",
          "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.5.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions/2.1.1": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1",
          "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource": "4.5.1",
          "System.Reflection.Metadata": "1.6.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions/2.1.1": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "2.1.11"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "2.1.1",
          "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource": "4.5.1",
          "System.Reflection.Metadata": "1.6.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.1.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.1.18157"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/2.1.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "2.1.1",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions": "2.1.1"
        },
```